# Error In launching selenium webdriver with port 0 on linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using following command to start selenium webdriver, on any free port in Linux

`java -jar /localdisk/selenium/2.53.1/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 0`

Sometimes my process starts on port 2 and then I was not able to launch web page via selenium.

I was wondering how it is launching server on port 2.

Comment: Usually this happens because there is a process running on the same port, or because the last time it is not closed properly. Maybe including `webDriver.Dispose()` at the end of your code, to closes all browser windows and safely ends the session, should solve the issue.

Comment: I think 0-1024 ports are reserved port, so why webdriver is getting started on port 2

Comment: Maybe starting a `hub` or a `node` could solve the issue? Then your command should be `java -jar /localdisk/selenium/2.53.1/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub -port 0`. Check out also the documentation in case: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#configuring-via-the-command-line-options